# New user created in linux terminal and the colors don't work?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal, colors

I've been working with Linux for a couple years as a CS graduate, but I've been using the root node the entire time. I know that isn't a good idea, so I finally added a user.

But the terminal's colors for the new user don't work.

In the root node, files were green, directories are blue text, highlighted in green, etc.

In my new user, it's all flat white.

I'd also like to change the default login to this new user, but don't know how to do that. When I launch Ubuntu, its default login is the root with no password.

I already edited the .bashrc file, uncommenting the line:

#force_color_prompt=yes

but still nothing. I also noticed changing this while logged into the new user also changes it in the root node. I thought the .bashrc file was unique per user?

Thanks!

Comment: `alias ls='ls --color=auto'`

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway I can change a bash file, so that I don't have to do it manually upon login, however?

Comment: *When I launch Ubuntu, its default login is the root with no password.* How exactly do you launch Ubuntu? Is it on real hardware? A virtual machine? Windows Subsystem for Linux? How did you add the new user, and what login shell did you configure?

Comment: @Cani687 put that line in `~/.bashrc` and `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: @steeldriver I just launch it in Windows Terminal with WSL. And I added the new user awhile ago, so I can't remember if I just did useradd or adduser.

Comment: @belkarx ~/.bashrc is the one located in root, right? And I keep seeing people say this, but get:
/home/alias/.bashrc: No such file or directory

Comment: @Cani687 `~/` expands to your `$HOME` variable, so no it's not directly in root. Type `echo $HOME` to see the path bashrc is in (ie my path might be `/home/belkarx/.bashrc`

Comment: @belkarx Hmm, when I do that, it prints home/myalias. But when I go inside home, even with ls -a, nothing appears to be in there. Should I create one? Just copy the one over from root?

Comment: Create a new .bashrc file in your user's home then? There's an example in `/etc/bash.bashrc`, just cp it as ~/.bashrc

Comment: @belkarx Would the command just be: cp /etc/.bashrc /home/myalias/?
EDIT: Ah! It worked! You're the best, thank you very much. Now if only I can change the default login, but I may just post a separate question. Already received a ton of help here.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked: I went into /home/ for my new user and noticed it was empty, so I just created a new directory named after my alias using sudo, and then copied (cp) the .bashrc from /etc/skel/ to my new directory (home/myalias/), also using sudo, and it worked. Thanks for the help y'all!